# MySQL Show value based on dates between START and END dates

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make simple house reservation system and my DB is like:

```
TABLE HOUSES
id | name
============
1  | house_1
2  | house_2

TABLE RESERVATIONS
id | id_house | date_start | date_end
=====================================
1  | 2        | 2015-11-02 | 2015-11-10
2  | 1        | 2015-10-02 | 2015-10-15
```

And I have no idea how to show reserved houses based on new reservation eg.

> id_house **2** **2015-11-05** to **2015-11-20**

System should output: House num. **2** is reserved on this days

Comment: on which day it should be display this message? and what is this: `id_house 2 2015-11-05 to 2015-11-20`

Comment: House num. 2 can't be reserved on this days because another reservation is on that house at 2015-11-02 to 2015-11-10  **id_house 2 2015-11-05 to 2015-11-20** <- thats a new entry to DB

Comment: then just check `date_start` or `date_end` are between those date

Comment: @bluto What if they're not between "those dates"? What if "those dates" are between `date_start` and `date_end`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input:** a date range for a new reservation (2015-11-05 to 2015-11-20)

**Output:** a list of houses that are already reserved for those dates

**Query:**

```
SELECT HOUSES.name, HOUSES.id, RESERVATIONS.date_start, RESERVATIONS.date_end
FROM RESERVATIONS
LEFT JOIN HOUSES ON HOUSES.id=RESERVATIONS.id_house 
WHERE
  RESERVATIONS.date_start < '2015-11-20'
  AND
  RESERVATIONS.date_end > '2015-11-20'
```

Something like that, but it depends on your logic (which I did not fully understand).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Bella :) but to fully work it sould be more:   OR RESERVATIONS.date_start < '2015-11-05'
  AND
  RESERVATIONS.date_end > '2015-11-05'

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE reservations
(id INT NOT NULL
,id_house INT NOT NULL
,date_start DATE
,date_end DATE
);

INSERT INTO reservations VALUES
(1,2,'2015-11-02','2015-11-10'),
(2,1,'2015-10-02','2015-10-15');

SELECT * 
  FROM reservations x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN (SELECT '2015-11-05' my_start,'2015-11-20' my_end) y 
    ON y.my_start < x.date_end 
   AND y.my_end > x.date_start;
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| id | id_house | date_start | date_end   | my_start   | my_end     |
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |        2 | 2015-11-02 | 2015-11-10 | 2015-11-05 | 2015-11-20 |
|  2 |        1 | 2015-10-02 | 2015-10-15 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: not quite on my mind. **reservations** DB should be extended by new reservation. Its for clients. so when client add new reservation successfully it should add ID 3 with date eg. **2015-12-03** to **2015-12-07**

Comment: Cool. Change the SELECT to an INSERT [...SELECT...] And reservations is a table. (I don't know where you get `2015-12-03 to 2015-12-07` from)

Comment: its reservation system, so client can add entry with custom date. this date is an example

Comment: Sure, but it's not the example which appeared in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT ho.*,re.* FROM tbl_house AS ho LEFT JOIN tbl_reservation
WHERE now() >= date_start and now() <= date_end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect :) thank You  **edit** but if date is higher than eg. 2015-11-10 than there is no results. It should output result because house 2 is reserved upto 11-10